# What is the best way to move data from AWS Ubuntu Server to an Amazon S3 bucket?

Tags: linux, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ubuntu-server

I am downloading large amounts of data ([link to data](http://maps.zh.ch/download/hoehen/2014/lidar/)) to an AWS Ubuntu Server with the hopes of eventually getting the data to a mounted S3 bucket. The problem is that if I were to download all of the data (e.g. >1TB of data) to the AWS Ubuntu Server with a 200GB disk, it would exceed the limits of the disk. Therefore, how can I efficiently transfer data to the S3 bucket given these constraints?

I've considered downloading a single file to disk, syncing to S3, and deleting the file although this approach seems terribly inefficient.

Comment: Why can't you upload it directly to S3? Why the intermediate Ubuntu server?

Comment: As far as I know uploading directly to S3 is not possible.

Comment: Either delete the file from the Ubuntu server once you've copied it to S3, or temporarily mount an extra EBS volume on the Ubuntu server with enough space for the job.

Comment: Why do you say uploading directly to S3 isn't possible? I do it every day...

Comment: @Chris, I must have been looking at outdated information. How are you doing it?

Comment: [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html) is the Java api- from here you can find other APIs including command line.

Comment: it's been possible to upload directly to S3 since before EC2 existed. You can do it with awscli too.

Comment: @tedder42 How is this possible with linux command line tools?

Answer (score 2):

Per the comments, it seems like the best thing to do is to use awscli to upload this from your local machine directly to s3.

Here are the basic steps:

- `pip install awscli` (or [use other installation methods](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html))
- [`aws configure`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html)
- `aws s3 cp /my/local/file.txt s3://bucket/key.txt`

There are many other methods available- but AWS's official commandline tool is well-supported and a great place to start for those with shell knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have huge data Files, I recommend you to use S3FS, which is a tool that mounts the S3 disk into your instance, so you can access all the files as it was a normal filesystem (which in theory is). here is a link so you can have more information

UPDATE 1:
keep in mind that the transfer speed is really slow (10 MB/s according to my tests), but I hope it will suit your needs

http://tecadmin.net/mount-s3-bucket-centosrhel-ubuntu-using-s3fs/